# QGraphicsItem position in the scene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

i'm working on a QT 5.3 Widget application on MAC OS X 10.9 and I've run into a problem.

In my program I have a `QGraphicsView view` containing `QGraphicsScene scene` contaning `QGraphicsEllipseItem parent` which i use as parent (to keep track) for other `QGraphicsEllipseItem`, lets call this last ellipse `child`.

Now, I'd like to get position of the `child` relative to `scene`.

Whenever I try to get to the coordinates in the scene now, it returns `[0,0]`:

```
 QGraphicsItem * parent;
 QGraphicsScene * scene;
 ....
 parent = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0,0,0,0);
 scene = new QgraphicsScene();
 scene.addItem(parent);
 ....
 new QGraphicsItem(12,12,10,10,parent);      //shown in the scene

 qDebug() << parent->childItems()[0].scenepos(); //returns [0,0]
 qDebug() << parent->childItems()[0].pos();      //returns [0,0]
```

How to get coordinates of the item relative to the scene?

I've read a few tutorials on the point but I'm getting lost in them or don't understand (english is not my native language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by setting the position of the item using function `setPos()`.

The function which your using to get the scene position is correct `scenePos()` or else you can also use `mapToScene()`.